# Meaning of the '.isRequired' when defining static PropTypes in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
static propTypes = {
  // Value to display
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  // Wheter this values was chosen by user or not
  isChosen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  // Gets called when user choses this value
  onChoose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

Why Should I add '.isRequired' in when defining the above PropTypes? I am a react-native beginer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define the PropType with `isRequired`, React will warn you when you use that component without passing that prop.

```
// -> Warning: onChoose is required but not provided
<Component value={val} isChosen={true} />
```

If you do not define it, the property is considered optional and no warning is displayed if you don't pass the prop.

```
// -> No warnings, since the props are not required.
<Component />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the React feature called `built-in type-checking abilities`. The `.isRequired` means that `props` element defined is required to be passed from parent component. If you don't pass it, React will give you a warning message.

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html